# Jquery push separate arrays to one array.

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this piece of code, that checks every checkbox that have been checked. I try to count the times the checkboxes is check.

Example if box 1 and 2 is checked it should parse the values to one array like ["1","2"]. But instead it keeps counting the array like ["1"], ["2"]. Even then try to push the count into the array it does not work.  This information i got from Chrome developer tool.

I tried to push it to the array like this:

```
 var count = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="check"]:checked').length;


 var arr = [];

 arr.push(count);
```

Maybe it is easier too understand if you guys see my code. Here goes!

> This function checks for change in the checkboxes, if they are checked
>   or not.

```
function chBox()
{
    $("#allCheckboxes").on("change", "input[name=check]", function() {
        var array;
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            var count = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="check"]:checked').length;


            var arr = [];

            arr.push(count);



            document.getElementById("toppings").innerHTML = count;
            console.log(arr);
            //alert($(this).val());
            // alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="check"]:checked').length);
            //document.getElementById("pieCrust").innerHTML = $(this).val();
        }
        else {


            alert("not checked");
        }
    });

}
```

> These to input with the name attribute "check", if the one I need to
>   push one one array instead of multiple arrays.

```
   <!--Pepperoni-->
                        <input class="form-check-input " name="check" type="checkbox" id="Pepperoni" value="Pepperoni">
                        <label class="form-check-label " for="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>

                        <!--Sausage-->
                        <input class="form-check-input chk" name="check" type="checkbox" id="Sausage" value="Sausage">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="Sausage">Sausage</label>
```

Comment: You need to declare your array `arr` outside of `$("#allCheckboxes").on(...)`

Comment: Why do you have two `var array` statements in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your array `arr` outside of `$("#allCheckboxes").on(...)`

Probably you're confused with your extra Array `array`, this extra variable is unused in your code.

```
function chBox() {
  $("#allCheckboxes").on("change", "input[name=check]", function() {
    var arr = []; // This is the place where you to declare your array.
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {      
      var count = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="check"]:checked').length;

      arr.push(count);

      document.getElementById("toppings").innerHTML = count;
      console.log(arr);
    } else {
      alert("not checked");
    }
  });
}
```